# I can't find why my loop is not working

Tags: c, sorting, for-loop

I am new to programming and I am trying to solve some problem in C. I can't understand something and I could not find any explanation on Internet. My code is as follows (I am just testing something)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sort(int[], int);

int main(void) 
{
    int myarray[5] = {3, 2, 9, 6, 5};
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", myarray[0], myarray[1], myarray[2], myarray[3], myarray[4]);

    sort(myarray, 5);
    printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", myarray[0], myarray[1], myarray[2], myarray[3], myarray[4]);
}

void sort(int values[], int n) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i = i++) 
    {
        if(values[i] > values[i + 1]) 
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
            int a = values[i];
            int b = values[i + 1];
            printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4]);
            printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
            values[i] = b;
            values[i + 1] = a;
            printf("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4]);
        }
     }
}
```

And what I get is:

- 3, 2, 9, 6, 5
- 0
- 3, 2, 9, 6, 5
- 3, 2
- 2, 3, 9, 6, 5
- **2** //(Shouldn't it be 1?????)
- 2, 3, 9, 6, 5
- 9, 6
- 2, 3, 6, 9, 5
- 3
- 2, 3, 6, 9, 5
- 9, 5
- 2, 3, 6, 5, 9
- 4
- 2, 3, 6, 5, 9
- 9, -1076375724
- 2, 3, 6, 5, -1076375724
- 2, 3, 6, 5, -1076375724

Comment: Hint: `int i = 0; i < n; i = i++`.

Comment: what is it that you want to do?

Comment: `i = i++` is undefined behaviour. change to just `i++` or `++i`

Comment: You're right! I am changing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In for loop check the `i= i++`. It should be only `i++`. Since `i++` is `i = i+1`

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Comment: Oh yes, I was so tired, that I did not see that

Answer (score 0):

the condition `i=i++` leads to an infinite loop. since your loop contains only an `if` statement,after certain updations the `if` condition always fails hence there is no change in the output but still the `for` loop is running for infinite times

Answer (score 0):

Also, the condition in the for-loop should be `i < n-1`.  In the given program, if i becomes 4, then `values[i + 1] = a` will write to `values[5]` which is out of bounds.